# как сделать из div картинку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет вообщем есть мини приложения для изменения лиц тобишь загружаем картинку перекидываем на нее шапку ,усы или что ни будь другое потом нам нужно сохранить этот результат но я не понимаю как это сделать вообщем это нужно реализовать только на jquery или чистом js можно еще использовать jquery ui подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать...?

p.s картинка находится в div а не в canvas ибо нельзя пихать в канвас по заданию((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На jquery и js этого не сделать. Нужен обработчик, например скрипт PHP.

Посылаете картинку и координаты картинок (шляпа, усы, борода, ...), скрипт PHP создает картинку. Дальше можно сохранить на диск или скачать.

Создать картинку средствами PHP http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=graph&page=003

Comment: или на клиенте отрисовать картинки в canvas и потом позволить сохранить через data url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112321/how-to-save-canvas-as-png-image - но "нельзя пихать в канвас по заданию"...